# Ajax reload div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Eu tenho uma página que exibe com Ajax informações do banco de dados dentro da div #addremoveprod, até ai tudo certo, tudo está sendo impresso perfeitamente.

Eu tenho também tenho em uma parte do código uma função de deletar as consultas feitas no banco de dados (também com ajax), que está funcionando perfeitamente. só que depois que eu clico pra deletar, eu quero que a div #addremoveprod, atualize-se sozinha, sem eu precisar da f5 na página.

já tentei tudo, segue o código:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var id = $('input[name=\'voucher-id\']').val();

// $.get('/natal-hospedagem/admin/voucher/'+id+'/getRequest', function(data){ 
//     console.log(data); 
// });
var tableInsert2 = "";

var getRequestVouchers = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/natal-hospedagem/admin/voucher/'+id+'/getRequest',
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data,function(key, value){

            var proximo = value['id'];

            tableInsert2 += 
            "<div id=\"prod-" + proximo + "\">"+

                "<div class=\"panel panel-default col-lg-11\" style=\"padding:0px;\" >" +
                "<table class=\"table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed no-padding-table\">"+
                "<tbody>"+      
                "<tr id=\"voucher-carrinhos-"+proximo+"\" data-proid=\"" + proximo + "\">"+
                    "<td>"+
                    "<div class=\"vertical-input-group\">"+
                    "<input name=\"voucher_carrinhos[" + proximo + "][titulo_produto]\" value='"+value['titulo_produto']+"' type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" size='40' placeholder=\"Titulo do serviço\" />"+
                    "</div>"+
                    "</td>"+
                    "<td class=\"col-lg-2\"><input  name=\"voucher_carrinhos[" + proximo + "][quantidade]\" value='"+value['quantidade']+"' type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" size=\"4\" placeholder=\"1\" /></td>"+
                    "<td class=\"col-lg-2\"><input  name=\"voucher_carrinhos[" + proximo + "][valor]\" value='"+value['valor']+"' type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" size='5' placeholder=\"200,00\" /></td>"+
                "</tr>"+
                "<tr>"+
                    "<td colspan=\"3\">"+
                        "<input name=\"voucher_carrinhos[" + proximo + "][descricao_detalhada]\" value='"+value['descricao_detalhada']+"' type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" size='40' placeholder=\"Descrição detalhada\" />"+
                    "</td>"+
                "</tr>"+
                "</tbody>"+
                "</table>"+

                "</div>"+

                "<div class=\"col-lg-1 col-xs-12\">"+
                    "<span role=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-circle  pull-right\" data-acao=\"excluir-carrinho\" data-id='"+value['id']+"' id=\"prod-"+proximo+"\" >"+
                        "<span  style=\"font-size:1.5em;\">&times;</span>"+
                    "</span>"+
                "</div>"+

            "</div>";



        });

        $('#addremoveprod').append(tableInsert2);
    }

});

$(document).on("click", "span[data-acao=\"excluir-carrinho\"]", function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('data-id'));

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/natal-hospedagem/admin/voucher/'+$(this).attr('data-id')+'/excluir',
        success: function(){
        },
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já tentou colocar a mesma function que usou para retornar os dados, no .ajax que excluí?
No success: function(){} que está vazio substitua pelo mesmo código do usado no success do getRequestVouchers 
 function(data){
        $.each(data,function(key, value){ ....

Comment: Perfeito, ótima ideia. Criei uma função carregarCarrinho() e no success do inserir e deletar eu chamei a função. muito obrigado ;)